# Retrieving value from condition in CDK

Tags: python, aws-cdk

When creating a condition as described here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk/CfnCondition.html.

```
my_param = aws_cdk.CfnParameter(self, "MyParm",
            type="AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>",
            default="/path/name"
        )

condition = aws_cdk.CfnCondition(self, "Example",
            expression=aws_cdk.Fn.condition_equals(my_param.value_as_string, "someString")
        )
```

How would I retrieve the value from the condition so I can use it in a different resource as input to a parameter? Like for example to sepcify if SSL should be used on a s3 bucket.

```
s3.Bucket(scope, 'Bucket', {
  enforceSSL: USE_BOOLEAN_RESULT_HERE,
});
```

Comment: Could you clarify with some code how you wish to consume the condition value?  What do you mean by "input to.a parameter"?

Comment: @fedonev lets say I want to use the output to determine of a s3 bucket should enforce SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Conditions aren't the right tool for the job.  Because CloudFormation Parameters and Conditions are resolved only at deploy-time, their values cannot be used as inputs to other CDK resources:

> [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/parameters.html): Because they are not available at synthesis time, parameter values cannot be easily used for flow control and other purposes in your CDK app.

Instead, the CDK recommends using [context](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/context.html) or environment variables to pass values into CDK code.

Comment: Might be worth noting that CDK recommends *against* using environment variables - the recommended approach is to set the configuration in the code itself.

Comment: [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/parameters.html):  _"The usual ways to pass values into AWS CDK apps are context values and environment variables."_  See the best practice guide for examples where env variables are [suitable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-constructs-config), such as top-level app settings and distinguishing between a dev/prod env.

Comment: The title of that section is "Configure with properties and methods, not environment variables", and it talks about only using env variables in a dev environment to provide the account name and region.

Comment: Your first comment (_"CDK recommends against"_) is inaccurate, as your second comment (\*cites recommended use\*) demonstrates.  Env vars are sometimes recommended, sometimes not.  We don't know what OP's underlying use case is, do we?  It's cool if you have a different view.

Comment: The second comment does not apply here, though, as it is strictly about `CDK_DEFAULT_REGION` and `CDK_DEFAULT_ACCUNT` env vars. I just figured it'd be worth mentioning that the best practices recommend against using env vars for configuration, that's all.